# Only first byte arrives when sending image over POST with python requests

Tags: python, arrays, post, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to feed a python flask server with some PIL images. The code that sends the requests looks like this:

```
...
for i in range(0,1):  
  ...
  chip_gray = Image.fromarray(chip)
  display(chip_gray) #This displays correctly

  byteIO = io.BytesIO()
  chip_gray.save(byteIO, format='PNG')
  byteArr = byteIO.getvalue()
  print(byteArr) #This prints correctly
  length = len(byteArr)

  url = "http://facerec-server.herokuapp.com/add_custom"

  querystring = {"label": lfw_people.target_names[lfw_people.target[i]]}

  headers = {
      'Content-Type': "image/png",
      'Accept': "*/*",
      'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
      'Host': "facerec-server.herokuapp.com",
      'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
      'Connection': "keep-alive",
      'Content-Length': str(length),
      'cache-control': "no-cache"
      }

  response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring, data={byteArr})

  print(response.text)
```

I have set up the structure the same way which I have tested it and verified it worked through postman. Though for some reason with this code (Ran from Google Colab), only the first byte arrives at the server. This is what is printed out there:

```
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238471+00:00 app[web.1]: b'\x89'
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238626+00:00 app[web.1]: Host: facerec-server.herokuapp.com
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238628+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection: close
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238630+00:00 app[web.1]: User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238631+00:00 app[web.1]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238633+00:00 app[web.1]: Accept: */*
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238634+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: image/png
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238635+00:00 app[web.1]: Cache-Control: no-cache
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238640+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Request-Id: dc61fe1e-5616-4b6d-8870-54b519be9f17
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238641+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-For: 35.201.212.71
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238643+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-Proto: http
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238644+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Forwarded-Port: 80
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238645+00:00 app[web.1]: Via: 1.1 vegur
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238646+00:00 app[web.1]: Connect-Time: 0
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238648+00:00 app[web.1]: X-Request-Start: 1574808401237
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238649+00:00 app[web.1]: Total-Route-Time: 0
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238650+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Length: 1
2019-11-26T22:46:41.238746+00:00 app[web.1]: CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([('label', 'George W Bush')]), ImmutableMultiDict([])])
...
2019-11-26T22:46:41.239577+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "server.py", line 49, in method_custom
2019-11-26T22:46:41.239579+00:00 app[web.1]:     img = np.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.data)))
2019-11-26T22:46:41.239580+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2818, in open
2019-11-26T22:46:41.239581+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))
2019-11-26T22:46:41.239583+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff04408e0f8>
2019-11-26T22:46:41.240073+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.12.43.130 - - [26/Nov/2019 22:46:41] "[1m[35mPOST /add_custom?label=George+W+Bush HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
```

Notice that the content length is set to 1 and only the first byte arrives.

Here is the code on the server that reads the image (and works with the postman request):

```
@app.route('/add_custom', methods=['POST'])
    def add_custom():
        print(request.data, flush=True)
        print(request.headers, flush=True)
        print(request.values, flush=True)
        start_time = time.time()
        data = np.array([method_custom(request)], dtype=np.float32)
        index_custom.add(data)
        index_ids_custom.append(request.args.get('label'))
        return Response(response=json.dumps({"time": (time.time() - start_time), "entries": len(index_ids_custom)}), status=200, content_type="application/json")
```

Have any of you got a clue why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem you have is that `Content-Length` is 1, which is what the server uses to read only one byte.

Can you print the headers in your client code to make sure `Content-Length` is not 1? Another option is to stop setting `Content-Length` yourself, as requests can do it for you.

Now let's look at the request call:

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring, data={byteArr})
```

Why are you wrapping `byteArr`? I think you actually simply want `data=byteArr` here. Also note that `requests.request("POST", ...)` can be shortened to `requests.post(...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was wrapping the byteArr that seemed to cause the issue. What a silly mistake!